# Retrieve info from another DE in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have 3 Data Extensions:

- one used as target which is the audience to contact
- one which stores products and email addresses. Here the email addresses match the ones present in the previous DE
- one containing products of fallbacks, used in case the email address of the DE target is not in the second DE

I would like to retrieve in the same ampscript info stored in the second and third DE. The logic behind is: if the email address of target DE is in the second DE, then retrieve the products in the second DE, otherwise retrieve the products in the third DE (where there is no match of email addresses)

The ampscript below only retrieve products from DE_2 where I have the list of products per email addresses.

```ampscript
%%[
VAR @email, @rows, @rowCount, @counter, @row, @productdescription
SET @email = [email]
SET @rows = LookupRows("DE_2", "email", @email)
SET @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
FOR @counter = 1 TO @rowCount Do 
SET @row = Row(@rows,@counter)
SET @@productdescription = Field(@row,"@productdescription")
]%%

%%=v(@@productdescription)=%% 

%%[
next @counter
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please share the ampscript you have written so far.

Comment: @LukasLunow added in the comment. Thanks

Comment: Please go through your questions, and mark answers as accepted.

Comment: @LukasLunow thank you but it is not working. should I change "retreive"?

Comment: Did you add this additional column to your faalback DE?

Comment: No, so which column should I insert? @LukasLunow

Comment: Keep in mind, that LookupRows function always needs a parameter to filter by. Hence you should add a column, like retrieve, where a fixed value (1) is present in all the rows of your fallback data extension - so they will be matched.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing one line in my Ampscript. It should be working now (if you add the column as I described)

Comment: Thank you, I made these changes but it is still no displaying the fallback products. I added the column Retrieve and populated with True (boolean field)

Comment: Sorry, I spotted another issue in your original code. Your definition of productdescription contained incorrect field name: Field(@row,"@productdescription") - I have fixed it to Field(@row,"productdescription")

Comment: Yes I have already fixed it. The problem is that it is not displaying the products of fallback. Should I add the column retrieve also in the target DE and put 1 in case the email is not in the DE_1?

Comment: No, you should be good. I also forgot an ENDIF. Sorry, too busy day today :-| See updated code below

Comment: Already added, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not displaying the fallback products

Comment: You can add intermittent outputs, to track where it goes wrong. I will recommend you to focus on displaying @rowCount in an output function, so you can whether you successfully fetch any rows there. I can't help you more without seeing your data extensions...

Comment: Also, so far you have not accepted any of the answers provided to your previous questions. Which is not very beneficial when asking for more help.

Comment: I am sorry, I accepted your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to have a fallback scenario in your script, which is triggered in case no matching records are found in your *vol_Newsletter* data extension.

Keep in mind, that `LookupRows` function always needs a parameter to filter by. Hence you should add a column, like *retrieve*, where a fixed value is present in all the rows of your fallback data extension - so they will be matched:

```ampscript
%%[
VAR @email, @rows, @rowCount, @counter, @row, @productdescription
SET @email = [email]
SET @rows = LookupRows("vol_Newsletter", "email", @email)
SET @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
IF @rowCount == 0 THEN
SET @rows = LookupRows("fallbackDE", "retrieve", "1")
SET @rowCount = RowCount(@rows)
ENDIF
FOR @counter = 1 TO @rowCount Do 
SET @row = Row(@rows,@counter)
SET @productdescription = Field(@row,"productdescription")
]%%

%%=v(@productdescription)=%% 

%%[
next @counter
]%%
```